# Zend framework - how can i make the robots.txt file?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Zend framework 2x how can i make `http://www.example.com/robots.txt` ?
i have following in bootstrap but it fails to understand the "robots.txt" only works when i go to `http://www.example.com/robots`

```
$route = Http\Segment::factory(array(
  'route' => '/robots[/:action]',
  'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Sitemap',
    'action' => 'index'
  ),
));
$router->addRoute('robots', $route, null);
```

Comment: why?? KEEP IT SIMPLE, just create robots.txt. If not use regular expressions inside route

Comment: YES - i did KISS first, but it does not work.

Comment: impossible, must work :) Or you have some wrong htaccess. There is a line thats says, go to file if exist, or go to index.php. Remember, empty robots.txt on some servers dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.txt` after `'route' => '/robots.txt',` and remove the `[/:action]`

So your code would look like this.

```
    $route = Http\Segment::factory(array(
        'route' => '/robots.txt',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Sitemap',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
    ));
    $router->addRoute('robots', $route, null);
```

**Edit:** I know some people would want it to be physical on disk, but this way you have a dynamicrobots.txt file which you can fill in with stuff from the database.

**Edit2:** And yes i know that you can write it on disk, but there's a pletora of ways you can do this.

Comment: You don't need a route for robots.txt!

Comment: Hes trying to do it routed so why not give the code for that, he's actually trying to get a sitemap out of it according to the code. but i understand you!

Comment: It is like handing a bulldozer to someone that asks for a shovel.  But okay, I will remove my downvote. In case you want a dynamic file and not a static file it is the correct way.

Comment: It works now this way. But does not worked by putting robots.txt file in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Add `robots.txt` to physical path.**

You can just add a physical `robots.txt` file in you public path. ZF2 will not reroute traffic to existing files in the public path.

So if you put the file inside  `/public/robots.txt` then a request to the following will simply load the file:

```
http://www.example.com/robots.txt
```

**2) Make sure the `robots.txt` has content**

The file needs content otherwise [it wont work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3533487/1697459).
So for example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**3) Check your rewrite rules**

If it still doesn't work you should check whether your rewriting rules (`.htaccess` or `web.config` file) are configured [according to the specs in the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)

Comment: first i added robots.txt file in public/ like you mentioned, but that does not worked.

Comment: @YumYumYum Are you sure the file has content?

Comment: OK - now it also worked because of the robots.txt had no content and i do not wanted to break my stable .htaccess file that is why i prefered to use the routing method.

Comment: @YumYumYum You are welcome. I do think my answer should be accepted though. Using a route for this is excessive.

Comment: YES - but i have also database and automated links, which all need be prepared and then shown as robots.txt file that is why for me the routing code was better, instead of placing a static robots.txt file. you answer is also accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have link to www.example.com/robots.txt simple save this robots.txt file into public folder

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my answer... What is new?